# How to register login using submit button in token based authentication web api using Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am new to Asp.net MVC

I am trying to make **Register**, my parameters are **Email, Password, Confirm Password**.

I don't want to do using ajax. I want to perform using `submit button`. I tried below code on my partial view

```
@using ProTest.Models
@model RegisterBindingModel

@Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"){ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.Email, new {@class = "form-control",@id = "txtEmail" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPassword", @type="password" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtConfirmPassword", @type = "password" })

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-rounded" value="Signup" id="btnSignup" />
}
```

> below method is created when I create the project MVC with Web api, I can register using ajax. But I cannot do it by submit button. I don't know what changes I have to make in this

**AccountController**

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change in Html.BeginForm parameter like this, it work well in my side.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("","api/Account/Register")) {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtEmail" })
       @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPassword", @type = "password" })
       @Html.TextBoxFor(si => si.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtConfirmPassword", @type = "password" })

        <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-rounded" value="Signup" id="btnSignup" />
}
```